# Find Format of Date in Java

Tags: java

How can we get the format of a date in Java??
I have a column which is in the date format . I want to find its format for every rows.
How can i do this ?
Ex --

```
COL1| COL2          |COL3
-------------------------
1   | 12-2005-31    |zzz
2   | 24 March 2009 |aaa
```

Comment: How would you distinguish between a numerical month and a day of month <= 12?

Comment: some date formats are ambiguous. 10-11-12 could be 2010 Nov 12 or 10 Nov 2012 or Oct 11, 2012.

Comment: why do you have different formats in the same column? it is not safe to interpret date formats through code. I would suggest that you fix the formats in the column/ source.

Comment: ok convert the date to string using dateValue.toString() . Once we get it in string check dis discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008000/string-to-date-with-no-format-specified

Answer (score 1):

As per this SO answer, [Generic way to parse dates in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953252/generic-way-to-parse-dates-in-java), there is no way to this. There are some partial solutions, but nothing definitive.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are storing date as strings in your database. I suggest you change the column type to Date or Timestamp in the database table and save yourself from parsing horrors.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply parse a string to form a Date because of the obvious ambiguity associated with the interpretation of the date string. For example, consider the date presented as "10/12/2009". One can interpret it as 10th of December and also as 12th of October. You can not map this string to a definitive date value unless you know the pattern it conforms to.

I agree with @Manish Sharma that changing the column type to Date would be a solution to your problem because Date values are stored as absolute seconds value starting from some fixed date in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do your own heuristic or simply said "guess". Create a list of regexp Patterns and use the first that matches to construct a Date instance. Hope that your date's formats in database are not too variable.